# I have a REST client APi but no detail on how the REST service is implemented . What technology do i use to make it useful for any implementation

Tags: rest, client

So i have a assignment to write some REST client calls to a REST web service which does not exist.
To work around it i created a mock web service using Jersey. But i am not sure what technology the actual REST service would use.

Please advise on what technology should i use to send down the REST calls to the server.
Also if possible also give me a sample of how to send down a XML GET request to the REST service.

Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please advise on what technology should i use to send down the REST calls to the server.

REST **is** HTTP. You can use anything that sends HTTP requests:

- [Jersey Client](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html)
- [Any](http://www.google.com/chrome) [web](http://getfirefox.com) [browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29)
- [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)
- [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)
- [carrier pigeon](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home)
- ...

---

> Also if possible also give me a sample of how to send down a XML GET request to the REST service.

It's just an [HTTP GET request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GET_%28HTTP%29#Request_methods). How it's built/generated/sent depends on what library and programming language you're writing the client in. But the actual request itself would look something like this:

```
GET /foo/bar/baz HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept: text/xml
```

Comment: okay so if the main REST service is not implemented using jersey i can still use the Jersey client right? That was were my confusion was about.

Comment: Yes, of course. Jersey is just an implementation of JAX-RS, which is itself a Java spec (JSR-311) designed to make it easier to create RESTful APIs. With or without Jersey, REST is still just HTTP.

Comment: so even if the rest service is not implemented in Jersey i can choose to use Jersey client to send down REST client requests.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Both Java and .Net environment has the tools to generate WebServices (SOAP and rest). What's your client development language ?

Answer (score 0):

REST :Representational state transfer in simple terms used to  send data between client and server . As
Client use some persistent URL for communication and it is stateless communication .

Java uses Jersey, the reference implementation of JAX-RS, implements support for the annotations defined in JSR 311, making it easy for developers to build RESTful web services by using the Java programming language.

So All u have to use for creating  services is  just some dependencies , bean configuration and some annotations (To Expose Service ) .
For calling REST Service  , u can either call from browser . Browsers like (chrome ,mozilla ) provide some plugins to calling REST service or u can create a client to call REST Service .